# JQuery Animate only runs once

Tags: jquery, css, hover, jquery-animate

I am trying to make all the divs that are of the .to-be-hidden css class to fade AND the div with id="feat-hover" to become fully visible when I hover over div id="mission".

Here is my code:

```
$(function() {           
        $("#mission").hover(function () {             
                $(".to-be-hidden").stop().animate({opacity: 0.5}, "slow");  
        $('#feat-hover').stop().animate({'opacity': '1.0'}, "slow"); 
        },          
        function () {      
                $(".to-be-hidden").stop().animate({opacity: 1.0}, "slow");  
        $('#feat-hover').stop().animate({'opacity': '0'}, "slow");     
        });  
});
```

Here is my HTML:
I replaced the blocks of text with want this to fade.

```
<div id="featured" class="grid col-940">
<div id="left-landing-container" class="left-cont" style="">

<div class="to-be-hidden">
<div class="left-div">want this to fade</div>
<div class="left-div">want this to fade</div>
</div>

<div class="to-be-hidden">
<div class="left-div">want this to fade</div>
<div class="left-div">want this to fade</div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="mission" class="keep-visible">
<div class="left-div" style="padding: 1px 0px 1px 6px; width: 97%;"">Mission Statement</div>
</div>
</div><!-- end of #left-landing-container -->
```

The scripts runs correctly when I hover for the first time and then it doesn't run again.

Please help!

Comment: Is it possible to have a fidlle with the problem?

Comment: what does your HTML look like?  add it to your question.

Comment: Doesnt seems like an issue here http://jsfiddle.net/TC7bb/ atleast with a guessed markup.

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/DZT6R/

Comment: no problem in this code, http://jsfiddle.net/mastermindw/K9XRE/
, you might have problem with other code on the page.

Comment: That's odd. I don't understand why it's not working for me. The only difference is that I have a bunch of local images in the HTML but that doesn't matter. And it runs perfectly but just once. If I just leave one action in the hover then it works fine.

Comment: Got it! I had forgotten a div closing tag somewhere. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will solve your problem

```
$(function() {           
    $("#mission").hover(function () {             
  $(".to-be-hidden").each(function( index ) {

    $(this).stop().animate({opacity: 0.5}, "slow");  
    $('#feat-hover').stop().animate({'opacity': '1.0'}, "slow");
 });},          
    function () {      
           $(".to-be-hidden").each(function( index ) {

    $(this).stop().animate({opacity: 1.0}, "slow");  
    $('#feat-hover').stop().animate({'opacity': '0'}, "slow");
 });  
    });  
 });
```

Comment: Sorry to grave dig but can you provide a brief explanation of what the problem was and how your solution fixes it?